# How to remove multiple elements from a JList at their given index?

Tags: java, jlist

I did do a search for this already but what I found were questions asked in which the index was only int and not `int[]`. Therefore, my question differs from those.

Here is my `ActionPerformed` method:

```
private void btnRemoveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    int[] selectedTask = lstToDoLists.getSelectedIndices();
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedTask.length; i++){
        Object getSelTask = lstToDoLists.getModel().getElementAt(selectedTask[i]);
    }
}
```

I have an `int[]` called `selectedTask` that gets the index of all selected items in my `Jlist` "lstToDoLists".

Then I have a loop that gets all the selected items in the `JList` using their indices.

How to remove those selected items in the `JList`?

Comment: I'm not certain, but you may want to sort the indices, and start with the highest index, and work your way down to the lowest, otherwise you may be removing the wrong elements.

Comment: It will depend on the type of model you are using

Comment: jList.getModel()).remove(index);

Comment: @SaviourSelf Whenever I hit the btnRemove in the GUI and I select multiple elements in the list it ends up selecting all of those between as well.

Comment: By `Comparator ` interface you can check element when you add list.

Answer (score 2):

With a for loop? If A [] holds all of the indexes you want removed from a JList, why can you not iterate through A [] and JList.remove each time?  If you start with the last occurence it won't change the placement of the lower indexed items.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Do I need a ListSelectionListener?

Comment: I wouldn't think so, but the problem is more complicate then just iterating over a list of indexes

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the model implementation, you should be able to remove any elements from your model using your indices.

```
lstToDoLists.getModel().remove(selectedTask[i]);
```

You can see about the `DefaultListModel` [definition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html).